# Stellar.js and bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get some parallax stuff to work. The blue balls is not behavioing as [here](http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/338_parallax/src/index.html).

They should be as a background and not taking up any space (is pushes the form down).

Link to my test site [here](http://www.posterlikes.com/page/)

Comment: you should probably fix the 2 javascript errors you're generating.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined plugins.js: line 142
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null-page: line 440

Comment: Those look like they're preventing your parallax stuff from initializing.

Comment: Sorry but i dont know how to correct or find these errors. But would like to know how.

Comment: Your css for the circle images is also wrong. You're applying a value to `top`, but since they're not `position:absolute`, it's not doing anything.

Comment: This is not a question, it's a plea for help. And unfortunately, it is unlikely you'll be able to solve this yourself, even with help from SO (which will be hard coming due to the nature of your request). Start small, learn how to use Firebug or the Google Chrome inspector. Read up on what CSS is. Good luck with your endeavors.

Comment: i am not good with javascript. Stupid question, how can there be a error when it is a plugin i have downloaded. There should not be any errors. Is it some sort of conflict with some other code ?

Comment: No, it's looking for a hash value on a link, which is only empty space. It appears you either have some bad markup or are sending bad values somewhere.

Comment: I understand that. You are saying that i have some errors. Can you see what i can do to fix that. Is it a conflict, spelling fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, as a real attempt at an answer -

Adding `position:absolute` to your images' CSS makes them at least start doing something, if you make sure the parallax gets initialized (I had to call the function myself, using the inspector, because of your Javascript errors).

Comment: I have added position:absolute that made it work. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it. And seriously, read up on how to use the developer tools in Chrome - https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview

It will seriously aid your efforts to do everything. Good luck!